# How to change default naming convention in Entity Framework CodeFirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my DB, the foreign keys following the following convention: `category_id`, `product_id`, etc...

How can I change EF's default naming convention and would I need to do it for every table?

Comment: you can use ForeignKey Attribute to set foreign keys . that will be better

Comment: these are the conventions based on code first entity framework  see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj679962.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the default name convention for FKs, then you need to create a new one. You will find a good explanation in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469439#example2), where explain how to create a new convention to rename the FKs.

Remember add the custom convention to your context after create it:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.AddBefore<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conven‌​tions.ForeignKeyIndexConvention>(new ForeignKeyNamingConvention());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [t4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) for entity framework. In these templates you can define your own table names, property names etc. Maybe this is not the best source about t4 entity framework templates. Try to google it.

Comment: How is this relevant?  Code First to my knowledge does not use T4 Templates.